# Pug not working in express when requesting from angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, pug

I have a webapp which I am currently working on.
Actually, I am sending a request from my AngularJS front-end like..

```
$http({
    method:"GET",
    url:'/verifyEmail'
}).then(function (data) {

}, function () {

});
```

and routing this request on expressJS back-end like...

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('.'));

app.set('view engine','pug');
app.set('views','./views');

app.get('/verifyEmail',function (req,res) {
    res.render('verify_email');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

In my project directory, I am having the `views` folder parallel to my expressJS file, and in `views` I am having `verify_email.pug`.

The problem is that when I am sending request from my frontend for URI `/verifyEmail` the pug is not rendering and not showing anything on browser. But when I send direct request from my browser for URI `/verifyEmail` the pug is being shown there.

Please help me with the same. If there are any confusions in the questions please let me know.

Comment: `res.redirect` does not respond with a HTML view. It redirects to `/verify_email` which is not a route in you application.

Comment: `app.get('/verifyEmail',function (req,res) { res.redirect('/verify_email'); });` looks odd. Try `render('verify_email')` instead of `redirect(...)`? Edit: See my answer.

Comment: if it worked with url and doesn't work with `http` request, i think it's `content-type` error, test it please `'Content-Type': "application/json"`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed redirect was a typo.. sorry I meant to write render() function only

Comment: @Maher where to change the content type?

Comment: remove the '/' before `verify_email` also please

Comment: http header in the after url, search google it's easy,and make sure your url is correct as @FaizuddinMohammed said

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed editted.. now it correct. Sorry for the typoss, new to stackoverflow!

Comment: Express adds the `text/html` to `res.render` calls

Comment: good luck .. try to answer your self for other users.

Comment: @Maher is is to be dome like this?? `$http({
            method:"GET",
            url:'/verifyEmail',
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).then(function (data) {
        }, function () {
        });` coz this is not helping me anything.

Comment: Well, your code above isn't doing anything with the response. Are you using developer tools to inspect the network request and look at the response? If not, how are you looking at the response and determining it's not correct?